# mysql multi count and sum with WHERE

Tags: mysql, case

i'm trying to build a query to check my stock.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS item_count,
reseller_id, sum(sold) as
sold_count, sum(refunded) as
refunded_count,**sum(case price when
refunded <> 1 AND sold=1) as pricesum** FROM stock
GROUP BY
reseller_id ORDER BY sold_count ASC
```

The above query will select all items and group them by each reseller with total items and refund count. The part in bold is wrong i want to get the total price(which is the sum for the none refunded + sold for each of the resellers (notice i group by reseller id)

Comment: sum(case price when refunded <> 1 AND sold=1 then something else something_else end)

Comment: perhaps i am missing the logic of cases, so i dunno how it should be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this with the case statements might work:

```
SUM(CASE
    WHEN refunded <> 1 AND sold = 1
        THEN price
    ELSE
        0
    END)
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT CASE price WHEN refunded <> 1 AND sold = 1 THEN price ELSE 0 END CASE ) a' at line 1

Comment: Sorry, that's my bad, I'm not sure that SELECT statement should have been there.

Answer (score 1):

Things that I noticed:

- You haven't ended your case. This is done by just writing "end"
- You haven't given a else case

Comment: perhaps it can be solved without the case, i just want to sum the prices based on WHERE..

Comment: yes, then you won't need the case at all if you are going to base the result of the where clause.

Comment: then please edit your reply. in case you understood exactly my question

Comment: you'd just have to write sum(price) in that case.

Comment: remember i want to sum prices only when they are sold and not refunded, no query so far was able to solve this

Comment: Then why write "i just want to sum the prices based on WHERE"? You need to be more clear if people are going to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a subquery like:

`SELECT SUM(price) FROM stock WHERE refunded != 1 AND sold = 1`

The complete query would look like this:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS item_count,
  reseller_id,
  SUM(sold) as sold_count,
  SUM(refunded) as refunded_count,
  (SELECT SUM(price) FROM stock WHERE refunded != 1 AND sold = 1 WHERE reseller_id=1 GROUP BY reseller_id) as pricesum
FROM stock
WHERE reseller_id=1
GROUP BY reseller_id
ORDER BY sold_count ASC
```

Comment: does this subquery obey the group by reseller_id ?

Comment: you are right, the query needs the same where and group by parameters as the main query. i'll edit the answer